reusing the same dataframe via cache
I have a DataFrame named dataframe_1, which is referenced in multiple parts of my PySpark code. To optimize performance, I intend to cache dataframe_1 so that subsequent references use the cached data rather than re-reading it multiple times.
Original Code:
dataframe_1 = spark.read.format("delta").table("schema.table_name")
dataframe_1 = dataframe_1.filter(condition).select(list_of_columns_needed)

# Planning to use cache here:dataframe_1.cache() so that cached data can be used by multiple references below.

# usage-1 of dataframe_1
columns_to_be_renamed = ["col_1","col_2","col_3"]
for c in columns_to_be_renamed:
    dataframe_1 = dataframe_1.withColumn(c, 
        when(trim(col(c)) == "", None)
        .otherwise(concat(lit(c), lit("_"), trim(col(c))))
    )

# usage-2 and other references of dataframe_1
...


I need to rename all column values. In the loop where I rename the values of columns mentioned in columns_to_be_renamed, I was necessiated to maintain the DataFrame name as dataframe_1. If I assign values to dataframe_2 as below ( I want some new df so that I can cache old df), only the values of the last column are updated (which is not the expected behavior; ideally, all columns should be updated as in the above code):
columns_to_be_renamed = ["col_1","col_2","col_3"]
for c in columns_to_be_renamed:
    dataframe_2 = dataframe_1.withColumn(c, 
        when(trim(col(c)) == "", None)
        .otherwise(concat(lit(c), lit("_"), trim(col(c))))
    )

Given this, should I cache the DataFrame dataframe_1 immediately after reading it, or should I cache it after the loop? My concern is that if I cache immediately after reading, subsequent references to dataframe_1 after the loop might refer to the uncached version from the loop instead of the cached one.
dataframe_1 = spark.read.format("delta").table("schema.table_name")
dataframe_1 = dataframe_1.filter(condition).select(list_of_columns_needed)

# New changes
dataframe_1.cache()
dataframe_2 = dataframe_1

# usage-1 of dataframe_1
columns_to_be_renamed = ["col_1","col_2","col_3"]
for c in columns_to_be_renamed:
    dataframe_2 = dataframe_2.withColumn(c, 
        when(trim(col(c)) == "", None)
        .otherwise(concat(lit(c), lit("_"), trim(col(c))))
    )

# usage-2 and other references of dataframe_1
...


I have validated the case - when we do dataframe_2 = dataframe_1, later change dataframe_2, dataframe_1 is not updated, retains initial data/state, as expected.
Is this the only way to handle it, or are there better ways to deal with such use cases?

This is a good way to handle it, but test the performance of .cache vs simply re-writing the data for your use case.  In a current project I note that .cache is 2-3x slower than simple writing the dataframe to disk and referring to that.
Additionally don't use withColumn, particularly if you are renaming a large number of columns it will hit your performance heavily, use select directly as you know the fields.
answers to the below clarifications:

why is cache sometimes slower - easiest way to understand that is that although both write and cache, by default, write out to disk, cache also has to attempt to keep it in memory, cache/persist to disk may also by default go to slower disks ymmv and it's always worth testing
why is withColumn slow - https://www.aizoo.info/post/just-one-more-column-what-could-go-wrong  select adds a single projection for all the columns you select, withcolumn adds a projection for each column you add.  withColumns is also more expensive than select (it needs to perform an additional action to get the actual column names).


thanks @Chris . Few points to clarify (1) even I noticed cache does not help mostly in my use cases. I have a data transformation job, which references same dataframe 4 times. When I cache, I can see single scan instead of earlier 4 scan. But dont see any runtime improvement, in few cases as you mentioned its taking 2X. What could be the reason for such behaviour based on your use case?
(2) why we should use select over withColumn? even if we perform a rename/transform during select, at the end it has to assign the transformed data to a dataframe. So what is the benefit?

thank you. on #1 regarding cache, I was mentioning about not writing into disk as dataframe, instead let the code run without any cache or intermediate write to disk. For ex: I have a data transformation job, which references same dataframe 4 times. When I cache, I can see single scan instead of earlier 4 scan. But dont see any runtime improvement. So Im letting the code as it is without an cache or intermediate write. Other than slower disks, are there any other reason that you noticed in general (or in your use case), where cache didnt help?

re cache, no, particularly if your datatsets are compute intensive re-computing is also an issue.  I'd add that there is a very important case when you would likely prefer writing - generated id's from an expression (e.g. unique_id), not writing will cause those id's to be re-generated so they can only be relied upon after an actual write.
